# Perl Mojolicious: Passing arguments to a code ref

Tags: perl, promise, syntax, mojolicious, coderef

In my Mojolicious Controller, I have:

```perl
my @promise;
foreach my $code (\&doit1, \&doit2,) {
    my $prom = Mojo::Promise->new;
    Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess(
    sub {
        my $r = $code->("Hello");
        return $r;
    },
    sub {
        my ($subprocess, $err, @res) = @_;
        return $prom->reject($err) if $err;
        $prom->resolve(@res);
    },
    );
    push @promise, $prom;
}

Mojo::Promise
    ->all(@promise)
    ->then(
    sub {
    my ($result1, $result2) = map {$_->[0]} @_;
    });
```

This works, and I can pass arguments (e.g. `Hello`) to my sub.

Now I converted `doti1()` and `doit2()` as helpers. So the code looks like:

```perl
foreach my $code (sub {$self->myhelper->doit1("Goodbye")},
                  sub {$self->myhelper->doit2("Good night")},
    ) {
    my $prom = Mojo::Promise->new;
    Mojo::IOLoop->subprocess(
    sub {
        my $r = $code->("Hello"); # this is ignored?
        return $r;
    },
    sub {
        my ($subprocess, $err, @res) = @_;
        return $prom->reject($err) if $err;
        $prom->resolve(@res);
    },
    );
    push @promise, $prom;
}
```

How can I continue to pass the same set of arguments inside the loop (e.g. `Hello`), without having to specify them in each code ref (i.e. avoid `Goodbye` & `Good night`)? I like the idea of passing the same arguments for each code ref: `$code->("Hello")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I converted `doti1()` and `doit2()` as helpers. So the code looks like:

```
foreach my $code (sub {$self->myhelper->doit1("Goodbye")},
                  sub {$self->myhelper->doit2("Good night")},
    ) {
    #....
}
```

Yes but you are calling the helpers from another anonymous sub,

> How can I continue to pass the same set of arguments inside the loop (e.g. Hello), without having to specify them in each code ref

so to recover the argument and pass it on the the helper, you just do:

```
foreach my $code (sub {my $arg = shift; $self->myhelper->doit1($arg)},
                  sub {my $arg = shift; $self->myhelper->doit2($arg)},
) {...}
```

or more generally as @Dada pointed out in the comments:

```
foreach my $code (sub {$self->myhelper->doit1(@_)},
                  sub {$self->myhelper->doit2(@_)},
) {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a comment...

The following was previously suggested:

```perl
for my $code (
   sub { $self->myhelper->doit1( @_ ) },
   sub { $self->myhelper->doit2( @_ ) },
) {
   ...
   $code->( "Hello" )
   ...
}
```

It could also be written as follows:

```perl
for my $method (qw( doit1 doit2 )) {
   ...
   $self->myhelper->$method( "Hello" )
   ...
}
```

It's a less general solution, but it's simpler and faster.

You might even want to factor out obtaining the helper.

```perl
my $myhelper = $self->myhelper;

for my $method (qw( doit1 doit2 )) {
   ...
   $myhelper->$method( "Hello" )
   ...
}
```